# Delete in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I must edit the complex code that is written with Fortran. Actually, I do not have good knowledge about Fortran. So in this post, I hope receive your help.

In this code, someone declare variables by header file-commonkb.h :

```
common/cntrl2/SWNU,BB6(500,500)
real*8 SWNU,BB6
```

when I run:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --log-file=log ./main
```

I have the error:

```
==4026== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4026== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4026== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4026== Command: ./main
==4026== Parent PID: 3252
==4026== 
==4026== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x324000, 0x28499000) (defined)
==4026== 
==4026== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4026==     in use at exit: 1,072 bytes in 4 blocks
==4026==   total heap usage: 10,875 allocs, 10,871 frees, 733,306 bytes allocated
==4026== 
==4026== 536 (24 direct, 512 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 4
==4026==    at 0x290C8B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4026==    by 0x292EF7F4: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.4.0.0)
==4026==    by 0x29474D25: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.4.0.0)
==4026==    by 0x2946C3B9: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.4.0.0)
==4026==    by 0x292EE867: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.4.0.0)
==4026==    by 0x284A9732: call_init (dl-init.c:72)
==4026==    by 0x284A9732: _dl_init (dl-init.c:119)
==4026==    by 0x2849A0C9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so)
==4026== 
==4026== 536 (24 direct, 512 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 4
==4026==    at 0x290C8B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4026==    by 0x292EF7F4: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.4.0.0)
==4026==    by 0x29474D25: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.4.0.0)
==4026==    by 0x2946C48B: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.4.0.0)
==4026==    by 0x292EE867: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.4.0.0)
==4026==    by 0x284A9732: call_init (dl-init.c:72)
==4026==    by 0x284A9732: _dl_init (dl-init.c:119)
==4026==    by 0x2849A0C9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so)
==4026== 
==4026== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4026==    definitely lost: 48 bytes in 2 blocks
==4026==    indirectly lost: 1,024 bytes in 2 blocks
==4026==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4026==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4026==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4026== 
==4026== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4026== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So what is your "this" problem. The leak? The "Warning: set address range perms"? Does your code run correctly? Please be specific. We may need a full [mcve] and an explanation of the purpose of the common block you show.

Comment: Dear Vladimir, thank you for your respond. My code run correctly. However, I want free all memory. I do not know to destroy block in fortran. Can you help me?

Comment: No, you need to show a [mcve].